# Python module PIL in windows 7

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I recently downloaded pycharm and used python 3.4 as my interpreter. I then downloaded the pillow package from python and tried the below code

```
from PIL import Image
img =  Image.open('kj.jpg')
img.show()
```

the JPEG picture opens in my windows default viewer. However , after 5 seconds - the image disappears and shows the below message 'There are no photos or videos selected'

this also happens when i use the img.load() argument.